# Apply st_intersection to a nested dataframe with map2

Tags: r, nested, tidyr, purrr, r-sf

Trying to apply function to a nested dataframe. Data sample:

```
# required packages
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# sample data
ln1 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2),
  lon = c(1,4,4,9),
  lat = c(2,9,9,5)
)

ln2 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2),
  lon = c(3,3,6,6),
  lat = c(15,0,15,0)
)

# function for creating an "sf" object
make_sf_lns <- function(x) {
  x %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% 
    st_set_crs(4326) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>% 
    st_cast("LINESTRING")
}

# converting data to "sf" objects - "LINESTRING"s
ln1 <- make_sf_lns(ln1)
ln2 <- make_sf_lns(ln2)
```

The following line of code represents what I intend to do:

```
st_intersection(ln1, ln2)
```

But for a specific reason I need to apply the `st_intersection` to nested dataframe like the following:

```
# implementation with `tidyr::nest` and `purrr::map2`
ln1 <- ln1 %>% group_by(id) %>% nest()

map2(ln1$data, ln2, ~ st_intersection(.x, .y))
```

When I do this the expected result is a nested dataframe with the intersection points, but instead the following error appears:

```
Error in st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) : Expecting a single value: [extent=2].
In addition: Warning message:
In if (is.na(x)) NA_crs_ else if (inherits(x, "crs")) x else if 
(is.numeric(x)) CPL_crs_from_epsg(as.integer(x)) else if (is.character(x)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `map2` iterates *in parallel* across the inputs, so in addition to iterating across the list column, it's also trying to iterate across the variables of `ln2`. Instead, use `map`, and specify the second argument inside or after the function:

```r
# iterate across the data column of this
ln1
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id data        
#>   <dbl> <list>      
#> 1     1 <sf [1 × 1]>
#> 2     2 <sf [1 × 1]>

# don't iterate across the columns of this
ln2
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> geometry type:  LINESTRING
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 3 ymin: 0 xmax: 3 ymax: 15
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#>   id               geometry
#> 1  1 LINESTRING (3 0, 3 15)
#> 2  2 LINESTRING (6 0, 6 15)

# equivalent: map(ln1$data, ~st_intersection(.x, ln2))
map(ln1$data, st_intersection, ln2)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant
#> throughout all geometries
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant
#> throughout all geometries
#> [[1]]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 3 ymin: 6.666667 xmax: 3 ymax: 6.666667
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#>   id           geometry
#> 1  1 POINT (3 6.666667)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 6 ymin: 7.4 xmax: 6 ymax: 7.4
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#>   id      geometry
#> 1  2 POINT (6 7.4)
```

For this particular example it would make more sense to unnest first, but presumably you have a case where that approach is less desirable.